# fast formatted file output of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, io, format

I have a *large* numpy array and I'd like to dump it into a file using ASCII format. I would like to specify the format. This works:

```py
import numpy

a = numpy.random.rand(5)
fmt = "{:.11e}\n"

with open("out.dat", "w") as f:
    for item in a:
        f.write(fmt.format(item))
```

but is slow because I manually loop over all entries of `a`. Is there a way to handle this in only one `write` operation?

Comment: `(fmt*len(a)).format(*a.tolist())` is a faster way of formatting the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

Provided RAM is not an issue, you can try formatting the array to a string and then exporting it:

```py
a_str = np.array2string(a, formatter={'float_kind':lambda x: "%.11f" % x}, separator='\n', threshold=np.inf)[1:-1]
with open("out.dat", "w") as f:
    f.write(a_str)
```

Comment: beware of the large array ellipsis